# How to import individual projects from Android Source Code

Tags: android, android-source

As far as I understand, all the built-in standard apps like (email, music, calendar etc) are built using the same API. So I should be able to import a  project like mail / music etc without checking out the full source repository of android. I'v been trying that but I am getting compilation problems like class resolve failure.

Am I doing it wrong? Do I have to get the full android source project to import a project like Mail ?

Comment: I am not sure if they are all open source. Android as OS is open-source, but applications might not be, only a few exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These apps are open source (mail, music and calendar). But they depend on internal classes and resources and can't be compiled with the SDK

Comment: I was almost able to compile the source except an Activity class was not found, Can anyone else verify this?

Answer (score 0):

You could pull a Git clone of some particular app. For example - the EMail app from

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Email/

The first problem is that Google are using MK files for building inside their android projects and Eclipse do not use them. But you can compile it because you have the sources, the XML resources and the manifest also.
The second problem is to deal with the dependencies. For example the gallery app may depend on few camera classes. You can manually copy them to your project.

Other way is:
Using Eclipse for writing code and testing if it builds correctly and using GNU Make 3.82 from http://www.gnu.org tool that will build the supplied Android.MK file and run the app.